# Format values in a view to currency

Tags: model-view-controller, view

I'm trying to display a couple of lines in an API return as currency.  The code for the view is below and I'm not sure if I can just do it in line or do I need to do it before it is passed to the view.  It's the last two lines in the table that need to be currency.

```
 @model Final_Project.Models.Root

<h2>Card Info</h2>


<table class="table" >
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Variant</th>
        <th>Card Number</th>
        <th>Rarity</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>High Price</th>
        <th>Low Price</th>
        <th>Market Price</th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var product in @Model.results)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@product.name</td>
            <td>@product.variant</td>
            <td>@product.cardNumber</td>
            <td>@product.rarity</td>
            <td>@product.artist</td>
            <td>@product.prices.tcgPlayer[1].high.amountInMinorUnits</td>
            <td>@product.prices.tcgPlayer[1].low.amountInMinorUnits</td>
            <td>@product.prices.tcgPlayer[1].market.amountInMinorUnits</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I've tried formatting one of the lines like this
`<td>@(product.prices.tcgPlayer[1].market.amountInMinorUnits / 100).ToString("C2")</td>`  My response was `3.ToString("C2")`.  That is obviously not currency ;).

Answer (score 0):

`@(...)` delimits an expression, so if you need to use parentheses to group internal expressions, you need to add *another* pair that spans everything.

```html
<td>@((product...amountInMinorUnits / 100).ToString("C2"))</td>
```